# Parameter override when a Verilog module is instantiated inside a VHDL module

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

Our simulator allows VHDL / Verilog mixed and our design uses an IP that written in VHDL (otherwise, our design is mostly in Systemverilog).
We are having problems as parameter overriding is not correctly working and we found the following statements from Simulator's documentation:

"By default, when a Verilog module is instantiated inside a VHDL design unit and default binding is done, VHDL generics are mapped to Verilog parameters using positional mapping."

It is saying that mappings of VHDL generics to Verilog parameters are done using positional mapping, not named mapping. The simulator offers a special option to change the binding rule to "named mapping" and that solved our problem.

My question is which standard specifies the binding rule when it comes to Verilog inside VHDL (or VHDL inside Verilog)? 
Or, is this an arbitrary choice the simulator vendor made?

Comment: Interoperability between languages with different syntax and semantics for names and types implies interfacing, a function of simulators and not of the languages themselves. It's an area just now reaching a wave of patent expiry and becoming eligible for standardization itself.

Answer (score 3):

The unfortunate truth is *there is no standard for interoperability between standards*. Why this is the case may be highly opinionated. But I can say that if more people bring this issue up to their vendors, the more likely it may get addressed.

Comment: Hi Dave and user1155120, thank you for your feedback. I now understand that specifying interoperability between languages is beyond language standard and is currently not well standardized. I thought there was a standard as vendors couldn't develop tools without knowing the behavior should be. Anyway, that ambiguity could create mysterious bugs. Hope the industry agrees on those that are left out.